# Data Driven Test using Groovy Scripting

Tags: groovy

I am using the below code to set the Property Values from Excel file to my Property Step and then pass it to the testcase.

When I run the Groovy code, the value from the last cell of the excel comes to the property step.

Please help me out to set the properties correctly.

```
import jxl.*

Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\Users\\naraysa1\\Desktop\\Address_Doctor\\DataSource_Address_Validate\\Data_AddressValidate.xls"))
Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(0)
RowCount = sh.getRows();
ColumnCount = sh.getColumns();
for (i=1;i<RowCount;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<ColumnCount;j++)
    {
        def c = sh.getCell(j, i).getContents();
        log.info c

        testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties_Address").setPropertyValue("ID", c)
        testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties_Address").setPropertyValue("AddressLine1", c)
        testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties_Address").setPropertyValue("AddressLine2", c)
        testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties_Address").setPropertyValue("AddressLine3", c)
        testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties_Address").setPropertyValue("City", c)
        testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties_Address").setPropertyValue("State ", c)
        testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties_Address").setPropertyValue("PostalCode", c)
        testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties_Address").setPropertyValue("Country", c)

        def TestStep =  testRunner.runTestStepByName("Search_Address")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your script you assign the value from each cell of excel into all properties and executing teststep for each cell.

probably you want to map cell values from one row to different properties and execute test for each row.

define the following map

(you can initialize this map from zero row of your excel table)

```
def header=[
  0:'ID', //means put cell0 into property `ID`
  1:'AddressLine1',
  2:'AddressLine2',
  3:'AddressLine3',
  4:'City',
  ...
]
```

and now your cycle will look like:

```
for (i=1;i<RowCount;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<ColumnCount;j++)
    {
        def pname = header[j]
        if(pname){
            def c = sh.getCell(j, i).getContents();
            testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties_Address").setPropertyValue(pname, c)
        }
    }
    def TestStep =  testRunner.runTestStepByName("Search_Address")
}
```